# From xsd to Json with all information

Tags: java, json, jackson, jaxb

Faced with such a task:

There is an xsd schema and based on it you need to generate json for swagger

In the xsd schema, the dimensions and annotation-documents are specified for the fields

What are the ways to transfer dimension indications and descriptions to json?

Or, for starters, how can I transfer this information to java-objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IDE plugins to convert XSD to JSON schema.
Alternatively, there are lot of binding mechanisms like JAXB etc to convert XSD to Java objects. It will self-annotate the java members too. You can then use json libraries such jackson to form the JSON schema.